# Mac OSX 10.8.4 semi freeze - is there a way to monitor why?

Tags: macos, monitoring, debug

My MacBook Air keeps semi-hanging. It lets me open new windows but it typically gets stuck after that. It's happens every 30-40 mins or so and lasts for about 5 mins each time.

For example I can open a new chrome tab but its stuck trying to find an Internet connection. I can open a new terminal window but the prompt doesn't come up for me to type instructions. If i close a program down the window dissapears but its still open until everything unfreezes. I can open the activity monitor and nothing appears strange.

Does anyone know of a way fr me to understand what is going on? Any ideas, monitoring apps, etc? I wonder if it is something to do with my Internet connection/dns/VPN, although I've turned most of the apps I have running for that off and it still happens.

Comment: Do you have Time Machine running? This happens for me whenever TM is backing up—I can't do anything with the machine, at least for the first couple of seconds when TM is writing data.

Comment: Did you look at the logs?

Comment: I turned time machine off and it doesn't appear to have happened again. Thanks for the suggestion! If you want to put it as an answer i'll accept - did you ever resolve the issue or just keep time machine off/wait till its done?